# Getting error while running AppFuse project: "Failed to execute goal on project"

Tags: java, maven, appfuse

I'm using AppFuse and I wanna create a multi-module project. I tried to follow the [AppFuse quick start guide](http://www.appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) so I used the below command to create the project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-jsf-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

Then I got **"BUILD SUCCESS"** Message but after running the below command (for running application):

```
Path/myproject/web ---> mvn jetty:run
```

I faced with this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:46.317s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 10 11:33:50 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/95M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:myproject-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:myproject-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in appfuse-snapshots (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-snapshots) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Unfortunately I faced this error both in ubuntu 13.04 and win 8.

How should I resolve it?

Comment: I read the error log you've posted and never found a problem with a JSF 2 jar nor a Java EE jar. Removed those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are using modular appfuse application.

In appfuse modular application two module exists: **core** and **web**.
Web module depends to core module.

So you should first **install** the core module.
Try this code in your core module directory:

```
mvn install
```

Comment: Tnx a lot ;) (damet garm dash mohsen)